# laravel 5.2 - Accessing Model in Controller Method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have added the line `use App\Post;` in the header of my PostController class.

When I try `$post = new App\Post;` in a controller method, I get the following error message

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Post' not found
```

What are some possibilities for why I am getting this error message?

Comment: Just try `$post = new Post();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already included the Post class, you don't have to reference the path again.

```
$post = new Post();
```

This should work.

Comment: just complementing the answer, you don't need to Specify the entire namespace of the class "App\Post" if you already declared the "use App\Post;" - So with that, you just need to use "Post" to call the class

Answer (score 0):

u can use facades..

```
$post = Post::all(); << return all row
```

Comment: try to explain some more. How will this help the OP and what was/is wrong with the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you used artisan to generate the Model. You may use eloquent as:

```
use App\Post as Post;
...
$post = Post::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to access the model via `App\Post` is because the file you are attempting to do this in already has a namespace, shown in the error: `App\Http\Controllers\App\Post`, which implies the namespace of the file is `App\Http\Controllers`.

Since you are not referencing the model with an absolute namespace (`\` at the beginning), PHP is looking for that class relative to the current namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...

$post = App\Post::find(1);    // App\Http\Controllers\App\Post

$post = \App\Post::find(1);   // App\Post
```

That explains the error. However, as mentioned by others, you have already `use`d the model in your file and can access it simply with `Post`.

```
$post = Post::find(1);
```